# Checking progress of deserialization using IEnumerators

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, deserialization, binaryformatter

```
public static object Deserialize(string path)
{
    using (Stream stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open))
    {
        BinaryFormatter bformatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        return bformatter.Deserialize(stream);
    }
}
SomeClass someObject = (SomeClass)Deserialize(savePath);
```

I'd like to create a deserialization process which includes progress of itself.
So possibly some kind of IEnumerator updating my progress field every frame.
Is it possible to track the position of the Formatter as it reads the file?

When I deserialize large files, I'd like to know how it's going..

Comment: I would stay away from `BinaryFormatter` to save your game data. It is very fragile, updating to a new Unity version can break all your save games. Stick with a JSON formatted save data or use a different 3rd party binary serializer than `BinaryFormatter` if you want to stay in binary.

Comment: I can see that it's also not really efficient.. what would You suggest I should use to efficiently store and load an array of more than a million 64-bit sized classes (so i reckon that's more than 200megs)?

Comment: I recommend [Protobuf-net](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net). However I don't know how easy it is to use with Unity, see [this thread](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/protobuf-net-unity-is-it-worth-it.288007/). However you also could write your own serialization methods if you are only searalizing a few types. just add a `public void Serialize(Stream destination)` and a `static YourObject Deseralize(Stream source)` to the types and use a `BinaryReader` and `BinaryWriter` to read and write the objects within the two methods.

Comment: Did you try NFX.Serialization.Slim.SlimSerializer or MessagePack?

Comment: MessagePack seems promissing, ill give it a try

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way I think is to approximate that by wrapping the Stream that is being deserialized and keep track of the position as the Formatter reads it.

```
public class ReadProgressStream : ContainerStream
    {
        private int _lastProgress = 0;

        public ReadProgressStream(Stream stream) : base(stream) 
        {
            if (stream.Length <= 0 || !stream.CanRead) throw new ArgumentException("stream");
        }

        public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            int amountRead = base.Read(buffer, offset, count);
            if (ProgressChanged != null)
            {
                int newProgress = (int)(Position * 100.0 / Length);
                if (newProgress > _lastProgress)
                {
                    _lastProgress = newProgress;
                    ProgressChanged(this, new ProgressChangedEventArgs(_lastProgress, null));
                }
            }
            return amountRead;
        }

        public event ProgressChangedEventHandler ProgressChanged;
    }
```

And usage:

```
public static T Deserialize<T>(
  Stream stream, ProgressChangedEventHandler callback)
{
  using (ReadProgressStream rps = new ReadProgressStream(stream))
  using (BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(rps))
  {
    rps.ProgressChanged += callback;
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    return (T)formatter.Deserialize(bs);
  }
}
```

ContainerStream:

```
public abstract class ContainerStream : Stream
    {
        private Stream _stream;

        protected ContainerStream(Stream stream)
        {
            if (stream == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("stream");
            _stream = stream;
        }

        protected Stream ContainedStream { get { return _stream; } }

        public override bool CanRead { get { return _stream.CanRead; } }

        public override bool CanSeek { get { return _stream.CanSeek; } }

        public override bool CanWrite { get { return _stream.CanWrite; } }

        public override void Flush() { _stream.Flush(); }

        public override long Length { get { return _stream.Length; } }

        public override long Position
        {
            get { return _stream.Position; }
            set { _stream.Position = value; }
        }

        public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            return _stream.Read(buffer, offset, count);
        }

        public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
        {
            return _stream.Seek(offset, origin);
        }

        public override void SetLength(long value)
        {
            _stream.SetLength(value);
        }

        public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            _stream.Write(buffer, offset, count);
        }
    }
```